# error Installing pymqi on 64bit windows machine

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

After struggling a lot to build pymqi ,i finally built it. but now when i import the pymqi library its throwing an error message :

```
>>> import pymqi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pymqi\__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    import pymqe, CMQC, CMQCFC, CMQXC
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

In case some one wants the build log :

https://codetidy.com/8314/

Comment: Do you use x86 (32-bit) python?

Comment: nope i used x64 bit python.   `>>> is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32
>>> print is_64bits
True
>>>`